# How can I specify the IP address of a website to fetch with PhantomJS?

Tags: linux, phantomjs

I'm trying to use PhantomJS to do some testing on a copy of a website I've put on a test server. Is there a way to specify the IP address and the "host" header on the command line, like with curl for instance:

```
curl --header 'Host: www.example.com' https://127.0.0.1/the_url_to_test'
```